# Authorize a computer on a iPad with broken touch screen

Tags: macos, ipad, ios

We have an iPad where the touch screen is not working. The rest of the device works fine, so we are using it for development purpose on our build server (we are using some third-party libraries which have not been built for the iPad simulator architecture so we must have a physical device connected to be able to build). The trouble is that we have bought a new build server and since our iPad is running iOS 7 we get the authorization dialogue: "**Trust the currently connected computer? Trusting this computer will allow it to have full access to your device and all of its data.**" Since we cannot tap the "Trust" button the new machine is not able to use the iPad for development.

So my question is if it is possible to authorize the computer without having a working touch screen.

Answer (score 1):

No.

If you could simply override the setting from the computer, that would defeat the purpose of iOS not exposing internal data until it has been approved through the touch interface.

Comment: Yes, I understand the purpose of the new authentication mechanism. I just hoped that there was another way, perhaps through iTunes using the same Apple ID that is on the device. But I feared that it wouldn't be possible.